# CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:41 (LIST): list sub-command REMOVE_ITEM requires list to be present

Tags: android, cmake, openscenegraph

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/Users/ben/Documents/work/OSGGuideApp/app/src/main/cpp -B/Users/ben/Documents/work/OSGGuideApp/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/ben/Documents/work/OSGGuideApp/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=/Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}
-- Check for working C compiler: /Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/ben/Documents/androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test GL_HEADER_HAS_GLINT64
-- Performing Test GL_HEADER_HAS_GLINT64 - Success
-- Performing Test GL_HEADER_HAS_GLUINT64
-- Performing Test GL_HEADER_HAS_GLUINT64 - Success
-- Jpeg missing
-- PNG missing
-- GIF missing
-- TIF missing
-- Curl missing
-- FREETYPE missing
-- GDAL missing
-- Windowing system not supported
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/ben/Documents/work/OSGGuideApp/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

CMake Error at /Users/ben/Documents/work/OpenSceneGraph/CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:41 (LIST):
  list sub-command REMOVE_ITEM requires list to be present.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/ben/Documents/work/OpenSceneGraph/CMakeModules/OsgMacroUtils.cmake:255 (INCLUDE)
  /Users/ben/Documents/work/OpenSceneGraph/src/OpenThreads/pthreads/CMakeLists.txt:33 (SETUP_LIBRARY)


CMake Error at /Users/ben/Documents/work/OpenSceneGraph/CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:42 (LIST):
  list sub-command REMOVE_ITEM requires list to be present.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/ben/Documents/work/OpenSceneGraph/CMakeModules/OsgMacroUtils.cmake:255 (INCLUDE)
  /Users/ben/Documents/work/OpenSceneGraph/src/OpenThreads/pthreads/CMakeLists.txt:33 (SETUP_LIBRARY)



The build system is configured to install libraries to /usr/local/lib
Your applications may not be able to find your installed libraries unless you:
    set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (user specific) or
    update your ld.so configuration (system wide)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have exactly this build log? Normally, the line `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!` plus following "See also" terminates the log. In any case, every error after "Configuring incomplete" is *secondary* - the harm is already done at this stage. But I don't see an error message before "Configuring incomplete"...

Comment: Yes ,because there is no static library output.

Comment: It is a **configuration stage** which is failed. It is executed before the **build stage** which produces executables, libraries and other project's artifacts. BTW, have you checked `CMakeOutput.log` file, which is pointed by "See also" line?

Comment: I can't find the error. The  CMakeOutput.log is  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beasonshu/logerror/master/CMakeOutput.log"